# Unable to add repeated field to protobuffer?

Tags: c++, compilation, static-libraries, protocol-buffers

So I am attempting to add a repeated field to protobuff. However, whenever I generate the file using make, add_linkage does not take any arguements as if it's not actually able to read in the type that linkage is suppose to take (it's another protobuffer.) What am I doing wrong in the protobuffer file?

```
package model_velocity.msgs;
import "vector3d.proto";

message ModelVelResponse
{
  required string name = 1;
  required gazebo.msgs.Vector3d angularVel = 2;
  required gazebo.msgs.Vector3d linearVel = 3;
}

message ModelVel_V{
  repeated ModelVelResponse linkage = 1;
}
```

Do I need to do something different? Do I need to call a different function to repeat the message? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`add_linkage()` doesn't take any arguments.  `repeated` message types' `add_x()` method return a pointer to a new, empty instance of the message.  You need to do something like `ModelVelResponse* resp = my_vodel_vel_v.add_linkage();`.  Then you can assign to the fields of the returned message as needed.

Comment: Then how would I repeatedly assign it? Just use add_linkage as an effective constructor?

Comment: Every time you call `add_linkage()` it adds a new `MedelVelResponse` to your message and returns a pointer to it, so yes, you can think of it sort of like a constructor (though this pattern is usually called a factory).

Comment: I see, well even though it compiles now, I am getting an error when I use it something about an uninitalized value.

Comment: I see, well even though it compiles now, I am getting an error when I use it something about an uninitalized value: Publishing an uninitialized message on topic[/gazebo/world/default_bot/image]. Required field [linkage[0].linearVel.x, linkage[0].linearVel.y, linkage[0].linearVel.z, linkage[1].linearVel.x, linkage[1].linearVel.y, linkage[1].linearVel.z, linkage[2].linearVel.x, linkage[2].linearVel.y, linkage[2].linearVel.z, linkage[3].linearVel.x, linkage[3].linearVel.y, linkage[3].linearVel.z,...] is the error message I received.

Comment: It looks like you haven't initialized the fields you need.  `add_linkage()` creates empty messages; you need to initialize the fields within them.

Comment: I am using set_allocated_(variable_name) though. I think I am incorrectly freeing memory. Here is the link to my plugin that is causing the issue: http://pastebin.com/kemWTuuL

Comment: You're passing a pointer to automatic storage to `set_allocated_foo()`.  `set_allocated_foo()` needs a pointer to heap storage that protobuf can take ownership of.  It's generally easiest to let protobuf manage its own memory.  You can use `set_foo()` for string fields, and `mutable_foo()` to get a pointer to sub-messages allocated by protobuf.  So something like `*res->mutable_angularvel() = stuff;`.